# Suggestions on solving a JPA persistence issue

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, foreign-key-relationship

I'm building a persistence tester. This project is responsible for creating and populating (with random values) any other object I might have. An object (obj1) is persisted in a DB and then read from it and stored (obj2), then I'll compare them (obj1 == obj2). To test if the data is persisted correctly. (Up to this point with simple objects, this is already working)

However, since I'm populating all the objects with random values I have a problem because the id's are random...
This makes it impossible to persist because FK's aren't corresponding to any id's.

To fix this, I was thinking of building a Factory for each object (and there are a lot of objects) and save the id's so that later, when persisting I could just get the id value and use it accordingly. However I have no guarantee this will work, you guys think so?

Have you guys had this kind of problem? How did you solved it? Do you have any other suggestions? They are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible not to populate IDs with random values but i.e. sequentially ? Would it solve the problem?

Comment: I've done that. Doesn't work, it's a complicated issue lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: As a first approach I would process a textual description of whatever dependency constraints you need your data to conform to into a testing script or script-driving data. Then generate the data in the required order.

A "test" seems to be an example persistence api client: it has a runtime state based on declarations in some language in which you call the persistence api; it emulates multiple persistence calls of a typical client. Such runtime state of a typical api client could involve any kind of dependencies between objects. Since you actually refer to FKs, presumably the clients  you are emulating have at least part of their state involved with ORM.

Those ORM declarations involve FK and other constraints. You may have another description of the same information, like database DDL or database runtime metadata, that is either generated by or generates those declarations. Maybe such info is actually part of the persistence api. You don't make that clear. A DBMS form for the info will be more likely to have the dependencies explicit.

Process the declaration or DDL or metadata query output text to extract relevant declaration parts. Eg by awk, sed, grep. Produce a dependency graph where the nodes are object class + fields pairs and a directed edge is to a dependent class + fields pair. (A FK is class + set-of-fields to class + set-of-fields but keys might overlap so the unit of dependency is field.) Find a partial ordering of these. You may be able to put the edges in a database table and do a transitive closure and/or partial ordering query. Or you could find a library to do this. (Eg JGraphT library.) The declarations may already be required to be in such an order. Generate data in order of increasing dependency. You might repeatedly generate groups of dependent objects then start over. Of course this should all be automated.

(More generally: In an ORM table of a set of objects forming a tree representing an ordered list there is a FK from a NEXT field to an OID field. But that is just a tiny part of an overall constraint (called a representation invariant) that if you follow all the NEXT references they form a tree! Maybe a sorted or balance one! That when walked produces an ordered list! The one described by the calls that built the tree! Presumably your persistence-tester requirements  state the sort of properties that your test client data/objects/state should have. Maybe it is only ORMish stuff. Eg PKs, UNIQUE, FKs, through:. Maybe its just FKs.)

(Be sure to set up your test project so that you can regression test the api and the tester. Eg store seeds. And although you might not be able to store all your example generated data you can check sum it and parts like tables so that you can check that it is likely to be the same as previous times.)

(Beware of random test data. Know the expected input-output relation. I was involved in a project with a multi-million-dollar bug (not mine!) using random test data.)